# Ввести и вывести строку с пробелами несколько раз

Tags: c++

Нужно несколько раз ввести и вывести строку, которая содержит пробелы. Сколько раз ввести-вывести - это на усмотрение пользователя. 
Пытался так, но не работает.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string str;
    int i = 0;

    do {
         cout << "str:";
         getline(cin, str, '\n');
         cout << "str:" << str << endl;
         cout << "repeat (1-yes/0-no)";
         cin >> i;
    } while (i == 1);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Программа компилируется и цикл повторяется, но когда переменной i присваиваю значение 1 дальше строка не вводится. Выглядит это так:

```
Input text: 
this is text 
Text: 
this is text 
repeat (1/0):1 
Input text:
Text

repeat (1/0):1 
Input text: 
Text

repeat (1/0):1
```

И так пока я не выйду из цикла. Подскажите в чем ошибка и как исправить.

Comment: а что если добавить cin.ignore() после cin>>i ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@kop_vlad](/users/10947/kop_vlad), никакой мистики.

Дело в том, что все символы после числа и `'\n'` вместе с ними после ввода 1 в

```
cin>>i;
```

остаются во входном потоке.

Реально в Вашем случае там скорее всего будут символы \r\n.

Просто добавьте

```
getline(cin,str);
```

непосредственно перед `while(i==1);` и все заработает.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще не рекомендуется использовать std::getline и >> оператор.

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098599/for-loop-skipping-getline) здесь есть ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо. Вставка cin.ignore() помогла.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    string str = "aaaaa\nbbbb bbbbb\nccccc cccccc ccccc\ndddd \neeeee\n", buf;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if (str[i] != '\n'){
            buf.push_back(str[i]);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < buf.length(); i++){
                if (buf[i] == ' '){
                    cout << "stroka: " << buf << " <--- soderzit probely!" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            buf = "";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Считывание с клавиатуры строк, состоящих из слов, разделенных пробелами можно выполнить с помощью приведенного ниже фрагмента программы.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
// <Другие директивы препроцессора>
#define SIZE 80
using namespace std;
void _tmain()
{
    string str;     // Объявление строки типа string
    char stc[SIZE]; // Объявление стандартной строки языка С++
    cout << “Введите строку из нескольких слов \n”;
    getline (cin, str); // Чтение строки до нажатия на клавишу ENTER
    strcpy (stc, str.c_str());  // Копирование с преобразованием
        . . .
}
```